# Cannot install web3 on nodejs

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereumj

When I try to install web3 using 'npm install ethereum/web3.js --save' command, I get the following error messages-

```
npm ERR! path git 
npm ERR! code ENOENT 
npm ERR! errno ENOENT 
npm ERR! syscall spawn git 
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing: 
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/ethereum/web3.js.git 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT 
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: are you using a windows or linux?

Answer (score 3):

Just use this:

```
npm install web3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `git` in your machine to have it working.

ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Windows :
here's the link to download it 
https://git-scm.com/download/win